# Blazor WASM ASP.NET Core hosted with Identity doesn't work when deployed

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I am new to Blazor so please excuse any terminology mix ups.

I created a Blazor Web Assembly app. I checked off "ASP.NET Core Hosted" and also chose authentication "Use Individual Accounts".

Visual Studio created a basic file structure with 3 projects, Client, Server, and Shared. I added the scaffold-ed Identity Pages to the Server project. I ran the migration, and everything works fine locally. I am able to register a user, login, log out, etc.

I deployed my app to IIS. I have two apps running on different ports in IIS. I also published the shared project. I also made sure permissions were set properly.

First I tried going to the server app. I try to open it up but it gives me a blank page.

When I access the client app, the website opens, but then the identity related functionality is broken. The page just says "Authorizing." I checked the console.

I get a weird error:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
>
> Unhandled exception rendering component: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Any ideas as to what is wrong? Did I set it up incorrectly in IIS?

The Program.cs for the client app looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Clients.Admin.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("Clients.Admin.ServerAPI"));

        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

The Startup.cs for the server looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => { loggingBuilder.AddSeq(); });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDbContextFactory<CredoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to access the server project but I added /index.html and it loaded the main page but then gave me this error: Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Project.Endpoints.Admin.Client'

Comment: This might be silly to ask, but have you installed the server runtimes for your version of blazor? Since you are new to it, this is often a step people forget.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for testing purpose, is better to start from a ASP.NET Core Hosted application.
Using this configuration you need only to deploy the Blazor Server project and at the same address you can access the Client (WASM) application.

In case you prefer to have two different project remember that the Server project doesn't have any UI out of the box.
You can add Swagger to this project in order to allow access to your Web API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

To use the Client (WASM) you need to deploy to IIS using the URL Rewrite module:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rewrite-urls-for-correct-routing-1

If you receive as error like:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

check you're appsettings.json configuration on the Client (the file has to be in the `wwwroot` folder, in the Server project is located in the canonical position).
Than check the this line in the **Program.cs** of your Client project:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("TestWasmAuthIndividual.ServerAPI", 
client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
```

the above example is from an ASP.NET Core Hosted application.
The `client.BaseAddress` has to be your *Server* address.

If you deploy with two different DNS name the situation should be something like:

- Server: **server.yourapp.com**
- Client: **[www.yourapp.com](http://www.yourapp.com)**

Now you need to use `https://server.yourapp.com` as `client.BaseAddress` in your Client project.

The error `Could not load settings ...` is related to the SSL certificate and the relative file you need to add to your IdentityServer configuration.
Look at this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#host-in-azure-app-service-with-a-custom-domain-and-certificate-1

This documentation is for Azure, but the certificate explanation is similar for IIS.
In practice you need to create/obtain a SSL certificate and you need to load it in your IIS/Azure configuration, then you need to configure IdentityServer to use you're certificate.

For testing purpose is better to use a *Development* certificate using the configuration that you can find in the **appsettings.development.json** of the Server project.

Copy the following lines to **appsettings.json** and try again:

```json
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I deployed my app to IIS. I have two apps running on different ports in IIS. I also published the shared project.

Which "two apps" ? From the Hosted project emplate you should only publish the Server app. It serves up the Client.
You should *not* publish the Shared project.

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

This means that an URL does not match the routing. You can debug with the Dev tools (F12). Figure out what API call your app makes and test that address with PostMan or a Browser.